# What is this effect called and how can i create it on photos with FOSS?

Tags: images, software-recommendation, effects, terminology, style-identification

**Searching for name of effect**

I want to design posters and I have stumbled upon this effect often, but I don't know what it is called. Thus I haven't been able to look for tutorials.

I am not talking about the colors or the ripped paper but the way the image has been transformed into dots of either of the two colors.

I am using GIMP and Inkscape. So, if you know how to do it in those applications I would be happy to hear about it.

I am also open to other applications as long as they are free open source software (FOSS). Of course, I am also grateful for just knowing what the effect is called.

---

> [image: Picture of Kim Jong-Un with the requested effect]

> [image: Picture of Trump with the requested effect]

Comment: Whenever you post material on Stack Exchange, you are doing so under a [CC-BY-SA license](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing). If you don't have the right to use these images, then you shouldn't be posting them here.

Comment: You can create halftone effects using raster software.  GIMP is free. Try that.

Comment: I "quoted" the images so they won't be attributed the CC-By-SA license.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first image has a **halftone** effect applied. The second image has an **etched portrait** effect, or an **engraving** effect. You may also see these referred to as **screen** effects, in reference to an element used in the printing process for such images.

You will find free halftone brushes for various applications. Inkscape is FOSS that can create vector halftones.

Comment: Thanks! this was the information i needed.